# Can't seem to get ember.js scope right with anonymous view

Tags: scope, ember.js

I'm trying to figure out what seems like it should be easy. I've got this for a View (Using Flame - I don't know if that's part of it). What I'm trying to do is display a 1-based numbered list of links for the user to click on and pick through the available images. The Layout works fine, all the HTML is acceptable, but when I click on a link I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object <(subclass of Ember.View):ember9452> has no method 'becomeKeyResponder'
```

And

```
App.Router:ember3456> could not respond to event App.ControllerA.jumpToImage in state root.visualGlossary.defaultState.
```

Google turns up nothing on these errors.

```
jumpToImage = Flame.View.extend({
    layout: {left: 0, top: 5, height: 26, width: 'auto'},
    classNames: 'image-links'.w(),

    handlebars: "\
        {{#each App.ControllerA.content.images}}\
            {{#view App.arrayIndexer contentBinding='this'}}\
               <a {{action 'App.controllerA.jumpToImage' }} {{bindAttr data-index='view._parentView.contentIndex'}}>{{view.test}}</a>\
               {{/view}}\
           {{/each}}\
        "
   }),
```

This as Controller A (the relevant parts)

```
App.controllerA = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    imageIndex: 0,
    //assume content.images is an valid enumerable

    jumpToIImage: function(e){
       this.set('imageIndex', $(e.target).data('index'));
    }
)}
```

And Controller B

```
Sylvius.arrayIndexer = Ember.View.extend({
   content: null,   
   test: function(){
      return this.getPath('_parentView.contentIndex') + 1
   }.property(),

  jumpToImage: function(e){
    Sylvius.vgDisplayController.set('imageIndex', $(e.target).data('index'));
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question, but in the interest of completeness and for anyone checking this out in the future: looks like you have a typo! `jumpToIImage` in controller A has two `I`'s, not one.